# Returning from all contributions of a contact to all contributions at all? a bug?

Tags: contributions

If I have a look at a contribution of a contact with more than 50 contributions (and let me show all of its contributions!) civiCRM does NOT return to the contact but to ALL contributions at all. Because we have more than 500 000, this takes ages!  Is this a bug?  CiviCRM 4.4.19  Drupal 7.39  Rolf  - ROBIN WOOD e. V.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the link to view all contributions from the bottom of the contributions tab, it actually takes you away from the contact record and directs you to the contribution search, with your search parameters (namely, the contact ID) prepopulated.  Once you're done viewing the contribution, you get taken back to the contribution search page (without your previous search parameters, alas).  I would agree that it's not as user-friendly as it could be, but I wouldn't classify this as a bug per se.  One workaround might be to open up the contribution info in a new tab, which will leave your contact's contribution search intact.

Lesley

Comment: I used a new tab, but this tab with the search for "all contributions" takes resources for a long time (closing the tab does NOT help!), so any other work on civiCRM takes very much longer!